# Google Maps iOS SDK: GMSPolyline & GMSMarker Performance Issue

Tags: ios, google-maps

I couldn't find any Google Maps SDK best practices on the inter-webs so I'm asking here. I'm working on an app with a large number of GMSMarkers (200+) and GMSPolylines (9000+). When I load all of them the map scrolling & zooming becomes laggy (kinda expecting that). Can someone tell me what's the best approach to this problem? Should I...

- Calculate the markers and lines within the current bounds and only show those?

  - and recalculate on scrolling?
  - what if the user zooms all the way out, it would still load everything?
- Is many two-point line segment polylines more performant or a handful of long complicated polylines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should find strategies NOT to add everything all the time.

only have that on the map that you can see.

That means: recalculate on bounds change but also: even if zoomed all the way you shouldn't need to display everything at once

Comment: adding everything is indeed not an option. so in the `mapView:didChangeCameraPosition:` method, I loop through all the markers and lines, if it's within the bounds, i set the map property, else I set it to nil. performance is better, but the markers and lines do not appear until panning stops. any thoughts?